# read single line from stdin and write to a file

Tags: bash, read, stdin

Is there a way in bash to read a single line from stdin and write directly to a file? Something like:

```
t="$(mktemp)"
while true
do
  [read single line from stdin] > "${t}"
  [nothing to read] && break
  printf '%s\n' "$t"
  t="$(mktemp)"
done
```

I have limited RAM available and expect lines that could be absurdly long. Otherwise I'd just do a while-read loop.

Edit:

I need to do some extractions and filtering. A more complete pseudo code-ish snippet would be something like:

```
f () {
  t="$(mktemp)"
  while true
  do
    [read single line from stdin] > "${t}"
    [nothing to read] && break
    printf '%s\n' "$t"
    t="$(mktemp)"
  done | while read -r file
  do
    if cat "$file" | grep -q '[criteria]'
    then
      cat "$file" | jq '[filter1]'
      cat "$file" | jq '[filter2]' >> [seprate file]
      [etc]
    else
      printf '%s\n' "There was a mismatch" > /dev/stderr
    fi
    rm "$file"
  done 
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a *XY Problem*, what's your end goal?

Comment: Except that, if they're getting multiple lines from stdin, as the code seems to imply, `head` might just eat all of it (e.g. `seq 100 | (head -1 > /dev/null; head -2)` prints nothing on my Linux), so using it doesn't really work. Then again, `read` from a pipe needs to read one byte at a time, really slow, to leave the read pointer in the correct place. But then, the text only talks about a single line, so it's hard to know what the actual goal here is. @fuumind, perhaps you should [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: The question is, why do you need the intermediate file? How exactly does it save your memory? When you write something to a pipe, but you still goes to the memory at some point.

Comment: Would not loading a string into a variable and then pipe:ing it to say jq absorb more RAM (both the bash variable and jq:s instance of the data) than just cat:ing directly from a file into jq?

Comment: So, you don't want to read a single line (only), you want to read _all_ lines from stdin and put each in a separate file, no? That would probably be best done in AWK. Then again, the whole thing, with the jq invocations too, would probably be best done in AWK or Perl. And well, Perl would also have modules for processing JSON, so you might not need to call on `jq` at all.

Comment: Anyway, how large are those lines, really? (How long is "absurdly long"?)

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank's for the pointers! I do realize that "absurdly long" is a very unprecise description. Wish I could be more specific but that's all I know.

Comment: @fuumind, my point about the line length is mostly that it might be worth just testing if it's an issue. Someone might say 10 MB or 100 MB might be "absurdly long", and it would be for a text editor, but I'm not all so sure it would be that bad for the usual text processing tools, or AWK, or even the shell. If it's 1 GB or 10 GB, then that might be different.